# Firebase in Cordova/Phonegap: Log in using Email/Password from within app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webview, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm running a webview from a cordova app and want to authenticate a user, I know they have the OAuth strategies but I need to use the email/password combination.

I'd like to keep things simple but may end up having to generate a token.

- Open an InAppBrowser that loads an auth flow for firebase
- Listen for that auth flow to be completed using this method: http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova%27s-inappbrowser
- Grab the result from the webview again and insert it into the webview firebase instance

I'm guessing that's not possible due to security.

My app is using Amazon login (required) so my alternative would be:

- webview loads InAppBrowser with our external url
- that loads Amazon auth, then generates a token for Firebase
- webview listens for token and grabs it, stores it in localstorage

Edit:
In the firebase docs on logging in with a username/password, I see it returns a token for the session and more information in the `authData` object:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html

Could I then take all the information from that object and send it back over to the cordova webview and then populate that Firebase ref with the information?

Comment: You might look at this tutorial I made.  It demonstrates email / password authentication with Firebase. https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/12/syncing-data-firebase-using-ionic-framework/

Comment: So you are allowed to send a username/email auth from within a cordova app? You don't need InAppBrowser?

Comment: @NicRaboy did you test it in the app store? Hoping to get someone for Firebase to answer this but if thats true then I can go ahead.

Comment: @NathanWienert Following up from our other conversation, did you get this question answered fully? Anything I can expand upon?

Comment: @RobDiMarco you answered it perfectly. I hope you don't mind, I posted our responses with personal info removed, is that ok?

Comment: @NathanWienert Sure, sounds great to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some answers from the wonderfully helpful support at Firebase:

First:

> You’re correct – anyone can make a request to sign up, and we don’t expose any capability to secure the url which people can sign up from for email / password authentication.
>
> The main reason that we require / enable origin whitelisting for OAuth authentication, but not for email / password authentication, tends to revolve around sessioning.
>
> The Firebase login server does not maintain sessions (via cookies or any other method), and so requests to the login server for password auth. requires a user credential (the password) for every request. CSRF is typically a risk when a malicious party can take advantage of a user’s session browser, i.e. make requests on behalf of the user to some page where cookies are automatically sent by the browser.
>
> Furthermore, we don’t have a great way to actually do ideal origin-based whitelisting for these pure HTTP requests. We could use CORS, but would have to fall back to JSONP for older browser environments that don’t support it. To complicate matters further, PhoneGap / Cordova apps don’t have the same notion of an “origin” at all, and from the perspective of a server – the calls are indistinguishable from any malicious party making an HTTP request with the same headers.
>
> The OAuth providers, however, use cookies for sessioning and do not require user invention for each auth. request. If you’ve approved a particular Facebook app, you won’t be shown any UI/UX or be prompted the next time that app requests your data – it will be invisible. When we do OAuth, we never have to send any user credentials to Facebook / Twitter / etc., because those are stored in browser cookies for facebook.com / twitter.com / etc. What we need to protect is a malicious party pretending to be a popular, valid Facebook app. and taking advantage of that short-circuit behavior that would get access to user data without the user’s knowledge.

My response:

> So, how is that secured? If anyone can make a request to sign up from a
>   cordova webview (which comes from no specific url, just the app iteself)
>   then I can't secure from which url people can sign up from? So any site
>   could use our url "xxx.com" in their config and start registering
>   users?
>
> That doesn't seem right to me.
>
> I think I still need to have an external url that is whitelisted by you
>   guys. That would have the login form and do the auth.
>
> But then my question is, can I transfer that auth back to my cordova app?
>   Is it somewhere in localStorage I can check? I'll have to run some tests.

And final response:

> Sure thing – we’re happy to help. I wrote much of the original client authentication code, and can speak to the design decisions and rationale that went into it. Be sure to let me know if you have further questions there.
>
> While we don’t store user passwords in cookies, of course, we maintain a Firebase auth. token in LocalStorage. Our authentication tokens are signed by your unique Firebase secret (so they cannot be spoofed), and can contain any arbitrary user data that would be useful in your security rules.
>
> By default, and when using the delegated login (email + password) service, these tokens will only contain a user id to uniquely identify your users for use in your security rules. For example, you could restrict all writes or reads to a given path (e.g. write to /users/$uid/name) by the user id present in the token (“.write” = “$uid = auth.uid”). Much more information on that topic available on our website.
>
> Your plan to spin up a server to authenticate users with Amazon and generate tokens sounds correct. This is a common pattern for our users who wish to use authentication methods that we don’t support out-of-the-box (ie Amazon OAuth) or have custom auth requirements. Note: once you’ve created those tokens and sent them down to the client, they’ll be automatically persisted for you once you call `ref.authWithCustomToken(…)`. Subsequent restarts of the app will use the same token, as long as it has not yet expired.

Answer (score 0):

This is a topic of interest to me too as I have implemented something similar , twitter digits (native android) + firebase custom login in webview.

I think, as recommended by firebase, you can use other authentication providers and then the firebase custom login.

Do you use the Amazon login in android native code ? If so after login, then generate a JWT token for firebase and use it to access firebase.
If all code is in Html/js app, then maybe you can use custom login and generate a token on your server after making sure its logged in to the Amazon.

The trouble with Android hybrid apps is the following: the JWT token (for firebase) should be created on secure system (eg. server side) not with android java code, other option for hybrid app is to do a http request to generate the token, but I find that less secure, anyone would be able to get a token by finding the URL, than I resort to generate token within android app code, you can change security key/seed for token when doing new releases.

In summary, I don't think firebase studied the problem of mobile hybrid apps.