# Firebase login across Ionic4 app and website - can I jump between app and website without the user having to login?

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I am looking to create an app in Ionic 4. I want to use firebase authentication for the app (as I think it looks easier than writing everything from scratch)

I would like the user to be able to login to the app. Then I need the user to click a button that takes them away from the app to a website to complete a payment (this is because apple/google don't allow donations through an app).

Can I use firebase authentication to do this? How do I preserve the users when I jump from app to website?

I found this question, but couldn't conclude it answers my above question
[Firebase in Cordova/Phonegap: Log in using Email/Password from within app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908823/firebase-in-cordova-phonegap-log-in-using-email-password-from-within-app/28951634#28951634)

Comment: Hey mate, what you said is correct, but I think I must have not been very clear in the question though. when the user A pops out to the website, i want the website to know that it is user A (without user A having to login) .  does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, you can use the plugin `InAppBrowser` to navigate to the website then after the user finishes the payment, you can write the following code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

This will check if there is a signed in user or not. If he is signed in then he doesnt need to login.

For example, if user enters the browsers and closes the application using swipe, then in the splash screen you can write the above code and navigate to the home page.

When the user clicks on logout, you can call:

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  console.log('Signed Out');
}, function(error) {
  console.error('Sign Out Error', error);
});
```

Then the user has to sign out of the application and relogin.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users